# Magento 2 After Migration Process Sucessfull From Magento1.9.1.0 To Magento 2.3.3 Customer Grid Throw Error

Tags: migration, magento2-migration-tool, magento2.3.3

Magento 2 after migration process sucessfull from magento1.9.1.0 to agento 2.3.3 then go to admin customers -> All Customer then throw error when i check in report following error throw

```
{"0":"Missing required argument $options of Magento\\Eav\\Model\\Entity\\Attribute\\Source\\Config.","1":
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to file **/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/Config.php**

Change  `public function _construct(array $options) to public function _construct($options)`